Почему в FastAPI при редиректе пропадает заголовок?
Не получается принять отправленный параметр в head:
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/create_head")
def create_head():
    redirect = RedirectResponse("/read_head", headers={'secret': '123459'})
    print('redirect:', redirect)
    print('redirect.headers', redirect.headers)
    return redirect

@app.get("/read_head")
def read_head(request: Request):
    secret = request.headers.get('secret')
    print('secret:', secret)
    return secret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app)

Консоль показывает, что установлено, но на принятии - исчезает:
redirect: <starlette.responses.RedirectResponse object at 0x000001BA06385390>
redirect.headers MutableHeaders({'secret': '123459', 'content-length': '0', 'location': '/read_head'})
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64147 - "GET /create_head HTTP/1.1" 307 Temporary Redirect
secret: None
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64147 - "GET /read_head HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

Что не так я сделал? Или есть какой-то подводный камень?
UPD - Добавил как JSONResponse отправлляет кастомный заголовок:

UPD2 - Попытки через CORSMiddleware:
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_methods=["GET"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


Никуда он не пропадает. Изучите как работает протокол HTTP.
Ваш заголовок secret честно ушёл в виде ответа к браузеру (и его даже можно будет увидеть в инструментах разработчика).
Но браузеру этот заголовок совершенно незнаком и он его просто проигнорирует. И сделает то что его попросили, перейдёт но новой ссылке /read_head, отправив стандартные заголовки (Host, User-Agent, Cookie и т.п.).
Повторюсь ещё раз — нет никакого способа заставить браузер отправить нестандартные заголовки в обычном запросе.
Либо используйте куки, либо делайте запросы самостоятельно из JS с помощью fetch.
UPD: Пьеса «Общение браузера и сервера»

Браузер: Эй, сервер, дай мне ресурс /create_head.
GET /create_head HTTP/1.1
Host: server


Сервер: Ага, сходи на /read_head и вот тебе ещё заодно заголовок secret: 123459
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: /read_head
secret: 123459


Браузер: ага, надо пойти на /read_head, а что это за secret? Не знаю такого заголовка, игнорируем.
Эй, сервер, дай мне страничку /read_head
GET /read_head HTTP/1.1
Host: server


Сервер: хм, никакого заголовка secret. Ну ладно, забирай страничку
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[...]




А почему тогда через JSONResponse он устанавливает и отправляет? Он же тоже от Response наследуется как и RedirectResponse

@Алексей я ничего не знаю ни про какой JSONResponse, но вы отправляете заголовки с сервера. Повлиять таким образом на заголовки которые отправит браузер нельзя.

Дак эти заголовки как раз таки с сервера и летят

@Алексей да. И браузер получит ваш заголовок secret. А потом сделает новый запрос к /read_head и никакого заголовка secret туда не передаст, потому что он так работает.

роут create_head  редиректит на read_head. т.е. Пользователь стучится на create_head, сервер создает заголовок и редиректит на read_head. Соответственно пользователь ответ получает от /read_head

@Алексей добавил описание как всё работает. Вы никак не можете понять что http работает по принципу запрос-ответ и редирект от сервера это просто указание браузеру сделать другой запрос по новому адресу, а не что-то волшебное заставляющее браузер заголовки ответа считать заголовками запроса.

Я сейчас еще пытался через CORSMiddleware провернуть, но тоже не получилось. Получается, что никак нельзя... Спасибо)
